# Retrieving tread depth when stairs not of Stairs class

Tags: revit-api

I'm looking at the publicly available model "210 King - Autodesk Toronto.rvt" which I upgraded from 2016 to 2018 (original 2016 version [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq57vqwwjro18cp/210%20King%20-%20Autodesk%20Toronto.rvt?dl=0)).  When I select a stairs object in the model, it has an "Actual Tread Depth" in the Properties Panel.

I want to access this tread depth in the API.  In the sample project that ships with Revit, the stairs are of class `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Stairs` (derived from `Element`) which has an `ActualTreadDepth` property.  But in this model, the stairs are all just objects of class `Element`.  Casting them to `Stairs` throws an exception.

Two questions:

- How can I access the tread depth?
- Why aren't these of class `Stairs`? (I'm new to the Revit API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access parameter values directly on the `Element` class. There is no need to cast to `Stairs`. That makes no difference whatsoever to the parameter access.

If you are new to the Revit API, please take a look at the [getting started material](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2). That will answer this question in more depth, and many others as well.

The answer to your 'why' question will help much, I'm afraid... historical reasons, the Revit BIM paradigm, underlying product features, you name it... There are often several different ways to represent objects in Revit. `Element` is the catch-all base case, as you have noted.

If the model you are working with was created using `Element` to represent the stairs, they may not have the property you are looking for. In that case, you may have to resort to other means to determine a useful value, e.g., (pretty complex) geometrical analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ok, so now I understand that an entity can have its `BuiltinCategory` as `OST_Stairs`, but be of class `Element`. That means I can no longer access the "Actual Tread Depth", i.e. `myElement.ActualTreadDepth` will not compile, but if this cast works, then this is fine: `((Stairs)myElement).ActualTreadDepth`.

The cast does indeed fail if the object is not of class `Stairs`. That means for the "OST_Stairs entities" I'm looking at, I can not access tread depth, but strangely in the Properties Panel, it *does* have a tread depth, so that can only be accessed in the UI?

Comment: Ok, so to answer this follow up question for any future folks: you can get it with `myElement.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.STAIRS_ACTUAL_RISER_HEIGHT).AsDouble();`.

Comment: Congratulations on solving and thank you for sharing that.